# Replace specific rows in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

In the following data frame,

```
col1 <- c("g1","g2","g3",NA,"g4",NA)
col2 <- c(NA,"a1","a2",NA,"a3","a4")
df1 <-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I would like to replace the rows with NA in col1 with corresponding rows of col2. Is it correct to proceed by extracting the rows containing NA by

```
row <- which(is.na(col1))
```

and then extract the characters from col2 by

```
extract <- df1$col2[row]
```

After this I have no clue how to replace the NAs in col1 with the extracted characters.
Please help!

Comment: You need to assign values in col2 to col1: `df1$col1[is.na(df1$col1)] <- df1$col2[is.na(df1$col1)]`

Comment: @akrun Right. This is why I add a comment and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `which`.  Just `is.na(df1$col1)` would be sufficient that gives a `logical` index.  The only problem with the dataset is that both the columns were `factor` class based on how you created the `data.frame`.  It would be better to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame(..)` as argument to get `character` columns.  Otherwise, if the `levels` in `col2` are not present in `col1` while replacing, this will give `warning` message

```
# Warning message:
#In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df1$col1), value = c(1L, 2L, 3L,  :
#invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Here, I am converting the `columns` to `character` class before proceeding with the replacement to avoid the above warning.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
indx <- is.na(df1$col1)
df1$col1[indx] <- df1$col2[indx]
df1
#  col1 col2
#1   g1 <NA>
#2   g2   a1
#3   g3   a2
#4 <NA> <NA>
#5   g4   a3
#6   a4   a4
```